# Getting error in copy constructor call when destructor is defined. When destructor is not defined, no error is seen

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I am getting this error when i define a destructor in the class and try to use copy assignment constructor. Without destructor, copy assignment constructor works just fine. Can someone explain to me what could be the issue?

**"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'
  what():  std::bad_array_new_length"**

Below is the code. Some of the class functions and constructors have not been pasted to avoid too much code.

```
class myvector
{
    int size;
    int *elem;

public:

    // constructor
    myvector(int size)
    {
        this->size = size;
        this->elem = new int[size]; 
    }

    // copy constructor
    myvector(const myvector &ob)
    {
        cout<<"copy constructor\n";

        try{
            elem = new int[ob.size];
        }catch(bad_alloc xa)
        {
            cout<<"Allocation failure. Please check heap memory\n";
        }

        for(int i=0; i<ob.size; i++)
            elem[i] = ob.elem[i]; 
    }

    // copy assignment constructor
    myvector& operator=(const myvector &ob)
    {
        cout<<"copy assignment constructor\n";
        if(this != &ob)
        {
            delete[] this->elem;
            this->size = ob.size;
            this->elem = new int[ob.size];

            for(int i=0; i<ob.size; i++)
                this->elem[i] = ob.elem[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    void update(int idx, int val)
    {
        elem[idx] = val;
    }

    int get(int idx)
    {
        return elem[idx];
    }

    int getSize()
    {
        return this->size;  
    }

    ~myvector()
    {
        cout<<"destructor \n";
        if(elem!=NULL)
            delete[] elem;
    }
};

int main()
{
    myvector ob1(5);
    myvector ob2(6);
    myvector x = ob1;
    myvector y = ob1;

    ob2.update(0, 15);

    // copy assignment constructor will be invoked
    ob2 = x;

    cout<<ob2.get(0)<<endl;
    cout<<x.get(0)<<endl;
    cout<<y.get(0)<<endl;
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You haven't got a copy constructor in that code.

Comment: Note: I second-guessed the duplicate, in the absence of a [mcve]. The error message hints at a different issue though.

Comment: @himanshu0811 -- *copy assignment constructor* -- That is not a constructor.  The word *constructor* in C++ has a specific meaning.  You do not have a copy constructor.  In addition, just posting class code does not show us how you're using this class.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie.. sorry about any confusion. Have posted Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: You failed to copy `ob.size` in your copy constructor.  In addition, your `try / catch` for the copy constructor doesn't make sense, since you just keep going as if nothing is wrong if there is a `bad_alloc`  thrown.